# Can I use Error Boundary component for fetching data from an API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React 16.3 which has support for error boundaries.
I want fetch data from an API but I don't know can I use error Boundary in this situation or not, and also I don't know use catch is better or use error boundary in this situation.
This is a big JSON data include images, price items,text for items and all of that stuff.
I'm quite new to React.

Comment: What data and how is it supposed to be used? Pleas, make the question more specific.

Comment: If you have a side effect (fetching data) you probably want to do it in your component maybe using 'try catch finally'. Use the error boundary for the purpose it was created for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. React error boundary components use custom methods `getDerivedStateFromError(error)` and `componentDidCatch(error)` that only trigger when a JavaScript error that breaks the entire React UI tree occurrs

Error boundary components don't catch errors in Promises, Fetches, Events and server side.